# Issue with IE11 download excel file

Tags: java, excel, internet-explorer

My application has a function that download database record to a csv file. 
When IE upgrade to version 11, and there are 50000 records to be download, click download button, after a while, a promoted message box was displayed on the bottom of IE11 window, then I click save, the 50000 records were download in the csv file; but if I click "open" instead of clicking "save", there will be only partial records be downloaded, sometime 3000, sometime 5000. 
Seems like the excel opened before file download complete.
Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are opening the file before it has completed downloading.

Try saving the file, waiting for it to finish downloading, then opening it.